# Vaadin23 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Client is resynchronizing

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

From time to time the Vaadin application becomes unresponsive and in the web console I see the following error:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Client is resynchronizing
https://example.com/VAADIN/build/FlowClient.638236c0.js:1

[image]

What might be causing this?

Comment: Which exact Vaadin 23 version you are using? There has been recent bug fixes that makes resync process more robust in versions 23.1.0 and 23.2.4.

Comment: I upgraded yesterday to 23.2.4

Comment: Is this happening with a view, which has a Grid using component column?

Comment: yes, very likely. I extensively use Grid with component column

Comment: Ok, this might be the reason why resync hangs. Note, it does not explain why resync happens in the first place. Resync can occur naturally if flaky networks. How frequently resync occurs in your environment? https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/10670

Comment: Hard to say how frequently  it happens… unable to catch this issue on desktop Firefox right now… but have the strange error on Safary iOS on my IPhone. Typically, once per hour websocket calls stop return response and I see an infinitive load bar on the screen. Only full page refresh helps. And this is still page with a Grid component and component column

Comment: Maybe this is the same issue

Comment: Just checked the server logs and may see tons of the following messages:

Comment: `2022-10-16 20:39:49.868  WARN 3548445 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-10] c.v.f.s.communication.ServerRpcHandler   : Resynchronizing UI by client's request. A network message was lost before reaching the client and the client is reloading the full UI state. This typically happens because of a bad network connection with packet loss or because of some part of the network infrastructure (load balancer, proxy) terminating a push (websocket or long-polling) connection. If you are using push with a proxy, make sure the push timeout is set to be smaller than the proxy connection timeout`

Comment: I use NGINX in front of Vaadin application

Comment: Could you please show the proper Vaadin configuration for NGINX and if needed, properties for Vaadin application? I'll test it in order to exclude this from the set of potential issues with resync

Comment: This is my current NGINX setup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74078464/vaadin23-with-nginx-and-websockets

Comment: Just to be noted the issue with has been fixed in Vaadin 23.2.5 and 14.8.20. So this is something different.

Comment: Thanks! In order to exclude the issue with Grid, I removed the Grid component from the project and simulated it with VerticalLayout. Right now I see the following issue also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74147029/vaadin-23-unable-to-fully-reload-application-after-redeploy

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems my resync issue related somehow to PWA. I disabled the @PWA annotation and the application start working normally right now